# F# Moq returns "Invalid setup on a static member"

Tags: f#, moq

#### in the repository interface file

```
type public IAccountRepository =
    abstract member Find: email:string -> firstname:string -> lastname:string -> Account
```

#### in the test file

```
open Moq
let mutable accountRepository = Mock<IAccountRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict)
accountRepository.Setup( fun rep -> rep.Find "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" ).Returns(account) |> ignore
```

accountRepository.Setup at runtime raises this error:

System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on a static member: rep => 
    FSharpFunc.InvokeFast
    (FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc

---

Note. I DON'T want to change my method into 
 this:
`abstract member Find: email:string * firstname:string * lastname:string`

Note 2 [added]
I don't want to use an *Object Expression* like this:

```
let accountRepository_2 = {
    new IAccountRepository with
        member __.Find a b c = account   // <--- this is the only mock I need
        member __.Create x = ()
        member __.Delete x = ()
        member __.FindByMobile x = account
        member __.FindByWallet x y = account
        member __.Read x = account
    }
```

is not a viable solution: I have 3 repositories and 2 other providers to inject... and I don't think is clean at all for this case.

What is that error?
Any idea of how to mock that method ?

---

[Update]
I updated Moq from 4.10.1 to 4.11.0. The error is changed:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: ... => 
FSharpFunc<string, string>.InvokeFast<string, Account>(...
```

I'm using **NSubstitute**:

```
let accountRepository = Substitute.For<IAccountRepository>()
(accountRepository.Find "aaa" "bbb" "ccc").Returns(account) |> ignore
```

and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not expect that there is a way to get this to work with Moq. The Moq library assumes that code follows usual C# coding practices and the way F# compiles methods with multiple parameters in a curried form is just not the way C# would ever define it.

When you write the following in F#:

```
accountRepository.Setup(fun rep -> 
  rep.Find "aaa" "bbb" "ccc")
```

Moq actually sees something that looks more like:

```
accountRepository.Setup(fun rep -> 
  rep.Find("aaa").Invoke("bbb").Invoke("ccc"))
```

Actually, it is even worse than this, because F# does an optimization when the compiler can statically determine the number of parameters and collapses some of the calls into `InvokeFast` call:

```
accountRepository.Setup(fun rep -> 
  rep.Find("aaa").InvokeFast("bbb", "ccc"))
```

A tool that does not know about this has no way of figuring out that this actually means calling `Find` with three arguments.

I think the best option would be to change the method signature (despite the fact that you explicitly said you did not want to do this). Alternatively, you could add a lightweitght wrapper for testing purposes. Yet another option would be to try the F# mocking library [Foq](https://github.com/fsprojects/Foq) and see if that handles this case better.

Comment: Thank you for the precious explanation (I was wondering where that "InvokeFast" coming from !). I know Foq and I think I already tryed it (I should have specified).    What do you mean by "Alternatively, you could add a lightweitght wrapper for testing purposes." ?    I haven't specified (yet) that using "Object Expression" is not a solution for me (I don't wan't be forced to mock N methods that are not part of the test itself) so I'm not sure this is the alternative you suggest. I hope you have some other solution...